# How to overlay calendar of events on existing clustered line and bar chart on PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 bar chart that shows the number of people who purchased apples and pears as well as 2 line charts to show the corresponding sales.

At the same time is there a way to annotate the high sale periods and low periods automatically?

On a separate table I would like to have an overlay of events on the same graph. How  can I go about it? [image]

Answer (score 0):

For the annotation section of your question:
You could try using tooltips to annotate the high and low periods automatically.
For example - Create a tooltip page that focuses only on the highest sales period and another for the lowest sales period. You can add both of these by adding two cards to the report and then making them transparent but with links to the high and low tooltips.